# WSAWaitForMultipleEvents returns timeout when send() is successful

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, networking, network-programming, winsock

I am working on a application which involves socket programming. I am trying to implement reset functionality in this application in case server is closed or crashed for any reason. For reset I need to reestablish communication between the client and server after manual restart of server. Now I am able to send request from client to server which server would process and send reply to client. `Send()` function at server side is returning with success but `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` function at client side is returning with `WSA_TIME_OUT` every time.

I restart my socket at client side with `SO_REUSEADDR` true value on reset. I am very new to network programming i am not able to understand why this is happening.

here is my code at client side. Its little messed up so please bear with me

```
void 
SocketListner::run()
{
    // std::cout << "Thread ID of SocketListener : " << QThread::currentThreadId() << "\n";
    if(_isFrameGrabber)
    {
        _listenForFrames();
    }
     else
    {
        _listenForRequests();
    }
}

void
SocketListner::_listenForRequests()
{
    DWORD eventVal;
    unsigned int eventSock;
    WSANETWORKEVENTS networkEvents;
    std::stringstream ss;

    int bufferLength = 500;
    char * msg = new char[bufferLength];
    std::string Msg = "";
    int retCode;
    int diff;

    while(!_done)
    {
        // Giving it one second less than the condition wait time
   //     OpenThreads::ScopedLock<OpenThreads::Mutex> lock(_destructorMutex);
        if((eventVal=WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(_eventCnt, _socketEvents, false, 3000, false)) == WSA_WAIT_FAILED)
        {
            ss.str("");
            ss << "WSAWaitForMultipleEvents() failed with error : " << WSAGetLastError();
            LOG_ERROR(ss.str());
            emit socketErrorSignal(eventVal);
            break;
        }
        else if(eventVal == WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT)
        {
            //OpenThreads::ScopedLock<OpenThreads::Mutex> lock(_mutex);
            if(_done)
            {
                WSACloseEvent(_socketEvents[0]);
                if(_eventCnt==2)
                    WSACloseEvent(_socketEvents[1]);
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }

        if( (diff=(eventVal - WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0)) == 0 )
            eventSock = s_sock;
        else if(diff == 1)
            eventSock = c_sock;
        else 
            continue;

        if((WSAEnumNetworkEvents(eventSock, _socketEvents[eventVal - WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0], &networkEvents)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            ss.str("");
            ss << "WSAEnumNetworkEvents() failed with error : " << WSAGetLastError();
            LOG_ERROR(ss.str());
            // break;
        }

        if (networkEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_ACCEPT)
        {
            if (networkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_ACCEPT_BIT] != 0)
            {
                ss.str("");
                ss << "FD_ACCEPT failed with error : " << networkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_ACCEPT_BIT];
                LOG_ERROR(ss.str());
                break;
            }

            if ((c_sock = accept(eventSock, NULL, NULL)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                ss.str("");
                ss << "accept() failed with error : " << WSAGetLastError();
                LOG_ERROR(ss.str());
                break;
            }

            if ((_socketEvents[_eventCnt] = WSACreateEvent()) == WSA_INVALID_EVENT)
            {
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << "WSACreateEvent() failed with error : " << WSAGetLastError();
                LOG_ERROR(ss.str());
                break;
            }

            if( WSAEventSelect(c_sock, _socketEvents[_eventCnt], FD_READ | FD_CLOSE) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                ss.str("");
                ss << "WSAEventSelect() failed with error : " << WSAGetLastError();
                LOG_ERROR(ss.str());
                break;
            }

            ++_eventCnt;
        }

        if(networkEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ)
        {
            if (networkEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ && networkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_READ_BIT] != 0)
            {
                ss.str("");
                ss << "FD_READ failed with error : " << networkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_READ_BIT];
                LOG_ERROR(ss.str());
            }

            if((retCode = recv(eventSock, msg, bufferLength, 0)) > 0)
            {
                int place = 0;
                while(place < retCode)  
                {
                    if(msg[place] == '\n' && Msg.length() != 0)
                    {
                        OpenThreads::ScopedLock<OpenThreads::Mutex> lock(_mutex);
                        //Naresh: Replacing std::vector by std::queue
                        _requests.push(Msg);
                        Msg = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(msg[place] != '\0')
                            Msg.push_back(msg[place]);
                    }
                    ++place;
                }
            }
            //Abhishek: Testing Complete else block
            else if(retCode == 0 || WSAGetLastError() == WSAECONNRESET)
            {
                //Abhishek
                shutdown(c_sock, SD_BOTH);
                shutdown(s_sock, SD_BOTH);
                closesocket(c_sock);
                closesocket(s_sock);
                int error = WSAGetLastError();

                if(!_initialize())
                {
                    _done = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else if(retCode == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                bool stopListening=false;
                int errorCode = WSAGetLastError();
                _processSocketError(errorCode, stopListening);          

                if(stopListening)
                {
                    LOG_WARNING("Connection with the partner lost.");
                    emit socketErrorSignal(errorCode);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(networkEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_CLOSE)
        {
            if (networkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_CLOSE_BIT] != 0)
            {
                ss.str("");
                ss << "FD_CLOSE failed with error : " <<  networkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_CLOSE_BIT];
                LOG_ERROR(ss.str());
                emit socketErrorSignal(networkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_CLOSE_BIT]);
            }
            else if(!_stopped)
            {
                LOG_ERROR("Lost Connection with Wall.");
                emit socketErrorSignal(networkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_CLOSE_BIT]);
            }

            closesocket(eventSock);
            break;
        }
        //Sleep(100);
    } //While

    delete[] msg;
    msg = NULL;

    // If any failure occurs make the _bDone  variable to true, as thread is no longer running
    _cleanUpCondition.signal();
}
```

here is _initialize function

```
bool 
SocketListner::_initialize()
{
    if(_IP.length() <= 0)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Host IP Address : " + _IP + " is invalid.");
        return false;
    }

    //Naresh: replacing vector by queue
    while(!_requests.empty())
    {
        _requests.pop();
    }

    WSADATA wsaData;

    if(WSAStartup(0x101,&wsaData) != 0)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Failed WSAStartUp() call.");
        return false;
    }

    sockaddr_in SockAddr;

    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(_port);
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr =  inet_addr(_IP.c_str());

    s_sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    //Abhishek:BugFix for reset enable address reuse else bind() will fail
    bool addrReuse = true;
    setsockopt(s_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*) &addrReuse, sizeof(BOOL));

    if(!_isFrameGrabber)
    {
        if ((_socketEvents[_eventCnt] = WSACreateEvent()) == WSA_INVALID_EVENT)
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "WSACreateEvent() failed with error : " << WSAGetLastError();
            LOG_ERROR(ss.str());
            return false;
        }

        if(WSAEventSelect(s_sock, _socketEvents[_eventCnt], FD_ACCEPT | FD_CLOSE)== SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "WSAEventSelect() failed with error : " << WSAGetLastError();
            LOG_ERROR(ss.str());
            return false;
        }
        ++_eventCnt;
    }

    if(s_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return false;

    int errorCode = bind(s_sock,(sockaddr*)&SockAddr,sizeof(SockAddr));

    if(errorCode == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        bool stopListening = false;

        _processSocketError(WSAGetLastError(), stopListening);
        return false;
    }

    if(listen(s_sock,10)!=0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: If an error occurs on a socket, in most cases it becomes unusable, and a new socket must be opened. Similarly if you shutdown() it. Maybe you're trying to send/receive over such an unusable socket?

Comment: Please show your actual code.  Your description is too vague to diagnose anything with. you are most likely using `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` the wrong way on the client side.

Comment: I have a added the code. Will Closing a socket and reinitializing it will be considered as opening a new socket ?

Comment: There is no such thing as reinitializing a socket. Once you close it, it's dead, you have to create a new one.

Comment: by reinitializing i meant that closing current socket and calling `initialize()` function again. Its like setting everything again. It should be like creating a new socket only.

Answer (score 0):

If the peer dies there won't necessarily be any events at all. The only reliable way to detect a broken connection in TCP is to write to it.  The first write to a broken connection will probably succeed but a later one will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. Now I am restarting all threads and sockets on reset in my application. After that i found server was not able to send because it was not able to connect new socket. I placed a infinite loop for trying to connect to client socket in my `sendData()` function. Which did the trick for me.